# SQL with grouping sets returns the initial table

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping

I have a sample table like this:

| name | manager | country | position | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | Mark | USA | Content Writer | 40000 |
| Kate | Mark | France | SEO Specialist | 12000 |
| John | Caroline | USA | Outreach Expert | 32000 |
| Alice | Caroline | Italy | SEO Specialist | 50000 |
| Philip | Caroline | Italy | Marketing Manager | 30000 |
| Julia | Caroline | Italy | SEO Specialist | 44000 |

I'm writing a query to get the avg. salary from the table grouped by different columns:

```
SELECT
    name,
    manager,
    country,
    position,
    AVG(salary)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    (manager),
    (name, country),
    (position),
    ()
```

However, the output is basically the same table I had in the beginning, just in a different order. Why is that? How do I fix this query to return the grouping I need?

Comment: I suspect you just want to add brackets around those sets. e.g. `((manager),(name, country),(position),())`

Comment: @EdmCoff: you should post this as the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the examples in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS), I believe you need to wrap the sets in brackets. e.g.

```
SELECT
    name,
    manager,
    country,
    position,
    AVG(salary)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    ( -- Added this bracket to OP
    (manager),
    (name, country),
    (position),
    ()
    ) -- Added this bracket to OP
```